# Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API and Documenting Return types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmldocument, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

For creating Help page for `API` methods, xml documetation has been used as this  [Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) and [ASP.Net WebApi Help Page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d132a2/workaround-in-Asp-Net-webapi-help-page/)   have described. One of my `api's` signature is like this :

```
        /// <summary>
        ///  this is getting a place's information
        /// </summary>

        /// <param name="placeKey">Unique key of place</param>
        /// <param name="checkIn">Checkin date </param>
        /// <param name="checkOut">CheckOut date </param>
        /// <returns>
        ///        Place's Information
        /// </returns>
    Core.Services.APIViewModels.PlacesViewModel GetPlaceInformation(string categoryKey, string placeKey, string checkIn , string checkOut)
```

The xml documentation is correct, except that we need to document the  `PlacesViewModel` return type. Actually the `PlacesViewModel` is a view model in another of project in solution. xml comments has been provided for it like here :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// a place information.</summary>   
    public class PlacesViewModel
        {
        /// <summary>
        ///unique number of place</summary>
        public long PlaceId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        ///  place's name</summary>
        public string PlaceName { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// places's key</summary>
        public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

But  it doesn't work and `PlacesViewModel` class attend in help page with empty value for Description's column in the table of `PlacesViewModel` as if there is no xml comment for them. How come can be provided a documentation for `PlacesViewModel`

If the `PlacesViewModel` move to the same project, it will work well!

Comment: What about including a class in your project which simply extends the other class?  You could add the comments to your class while still using the properties of the other.  Far from Ideal I know but would probably overcome this problem.

Comment: Although I need a significant solution, I  do that finally if there weren't any solutions, thanks